# How to create a Delete an item in DB from a confirmation pop up in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, mysql, django

I have built a website that contains a table with posts and a button of delete.
When you click on the delete button it shows a pop up and when you click "confirm" it supposed to delete the item.

I don't know how to connect the confirm button to the urls.py that deletes my item.

1. What should I add to the class of PostDelete?
2. Should I add something to the HTML? The form is using POST...

As you can see I have in comment a few things I tried like post.delete() but neither of them worked well...

Please help me, I am very confused and didn't find any guide for confirmation fade option with django :(

Thank you!

index.html-

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal" href="{% url 'delete_post' server.id %}">Delete <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" </span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal">Edit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" </span></button>
<div id ="MyModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                    <h4>Are you sure you want to delete?</h4>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" value="Confirm delete"/>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </form>
            </div>
</div>
```

views.py -

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, UpdateView, DeleteView,     CreateView
from DevOpsWeb.forms import HomeForm
from DevOpsWeb.models import serverlist
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class HomeView(TemplateView):

template_name = 'serverlist.html'
#    def home(self, request):
#        entries = serverlist.objects.all()
#        return render_to_response('serverlist.html', {'Post' : entries })

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()
        args = {'form' : form, 'posts' : posts}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
    def post(self,request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()
        if form.is_valid(): # Checks if validation passed
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            text = form.cleaned_data['ServerName']
            form = HomeForm()
            return redirect('serverlist')
        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name,args)

class PostDelete(DeleteView):
    model = serverlist
    success_url = reverse_lazy('serverlist') # This is where this view will


#    def delete(self,request,id=None):
#        post = get_object_or_404(serverlist,id=id)
#        post.delete()
#        return redirect('serverlist')
```

urls.py -

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from DevOpsWeb.views import HomeView
from DevOpsWeb.views import PostDelete
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='serverlist'),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
     url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
     url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostDelete.as_view(),     name="delete_post"),
     url(r'^django_popup_view_field/',     include('django_popup_view_field.urls', namespace="django_popup_view_field")),
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am showing you a way that you can proceed:

```
{% for server in posts %} 
<tr>
    <td>{{ server.ServerName }}</td>
    <td>{{ server.Owner }}</td>
    <td>{{ server.Project }}</td>
    <td>{{ server.Description }}</td>
    <td>{{ server.IP }}</td>
    <td>{{ server.ILO }}</td> 
    <td>{{ server.Rack }}</td>
    <td>{{ server.Status }}</td>
    <td><a href="#delete-server-{{server.id}}" data-toggle="modal">Delete Server</a></td>

    <!-- The modal needs to be inside the loop, with the id from href attr of delete button -->

    <div class="modal-dialog" id="delete-server-{{server.id}}">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="{% url 'delete_post' server.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                    <h4>Are you sure you want to delete?</h4>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">Confirm delete</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </form>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</tr>
{% endfor  %}
```

Comment: isnt it supposed to be?
<form action="{% url 'delete_post' {{ server.id }} %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

Comment: Yes, it's better to do it through form POST

Comment: That's the error i got: :(
    TemplateSyntaxError at /
    Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'

<form action="{% url 'delete_post' {{ server.id }} %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

Comment: The error is because the {{ }} for the variable close by accident the { of the url

Comment: I've added the form inside the modal, so you can proceed that way !

Comment: Can I talk to you by email/facebook?

Comment: join me there: fullcrap90@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you! Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your form tag in index.html should be like

```
<form action="{% url 'delete_post' server.id %}" method="post">
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: Oh and one problem! it deletes the first item always and not the item the button next to? Why is it? I do wrote server.id! It alwasys deletes the first one.
Do you have any idea?